# Where is the JavaScriptCore library that React Native uses on Android located in the repository

Tags: android, react-native, javascriptcore

I am trying to measure the binary size impact of JavaScriptCore being packaged with React Native on Android. Looking at the React Native [repository](https://github.com/facebook/react-native), I'm not sure where that code lives. I found a directory `react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact/` which seems relevant because it has files like `JSCExecutor.h` but I'm not entirely sure. I was expecting JSC to get packaged on Android as a single binary file, possibly a `.so` file.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `build` directory after compiling a React Native project, I found the following `libjsc.so` files (one per architecture), which I think is what i was looking for. I wonder though if JavaScriptCore would work on its own just with that `.so` file or if there are any other dependencies for it from other `.so` files, such as `libicu_common.so` which also lives in that folder.

```
./android/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/org.webkit/android-jsc/r174650/jni/x86/libjsc.so
./android/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/org.webkit/android-jsc/r174650/jni/armeabi-v7a/libjsc.so
```